# "it’s the one all the pros use." meaning of the "pros"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, vocabulary

A: Mr. Miller, how are you?

B: I’m fine. How are you?

A: Very fine. I suppose you wanna see it again?

B: If you don’t mind.

A: You know where it is.

B: Oh, yeah.

A: You know, if I charged you a dollar every time you came to examine the machine, you’d probably own it. You know, it’s the one all the **pros** use. Mariah Carey. Beyonce. Gwen Stefani.

The source:
Taken 1 movie.

Comment: pros=professionals

Comment: Oh sir, thank you. I'd mixed it with "pros and cons".

Comment: Well, a lot of pros are cons, and a lot of cons are pros.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the OP could have found out in a dictionary?

> **pro**<sup>1</sup>
> noun (plural pros) *informal*
> a professional, especially in sports

*New Oxford American Dictionary*